# Limits of an equation

Tags: limits

I was asked to find the limiting behavior of the following equation:
$$\frac{C_V}{NK_B}\left(t\right)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1} \left(1-\omega^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\left(\frac{\omega}{t}\right)^2 e^{\frac{\omega}{t}}}{\left(e^{\frac{\omega}{t}}-1\right)^2}$$

$t\rightarrow \infty :$

$t\rightarrow 0 :$

Could you please tell me how to find the limits. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 1:  $t \to \infty$

Let's observe the behavior for large $t$ of the expression

$$\frac{\left(\frac{\omega}{t}\right)^2 e^{\omega /t}}{\left(e^{\omega /t}-1\right)^2}$$

We note that $e^{\omega /t}=1+(\omega /t) +O((\omega /t)^2)$ for large $t$.  Thus,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\left(\frac{\omega}{t}\right)^2 e^{\omega /t}}{\left(e^{\omega /t}-1\right)^2}&=1+\frac{\omega}{t}+O\left(\left(\frac{\omega}{t}\right)^2\right)\\&=1+O\left(\frac{\omega}{t}\right)\\
&\to 1 \,\,\text{as} \,\,t\to \infty
\end{align}$$

The resulting integral has a limit

$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^1 \frac{d\omega}{\sqrt{1-\omega^2}}=1$$

---

Case 2: $t \to 0$

Here we note that as $t \to 0$, the denominator term grows asymptotically like $e^{2\omega /t}$ and overwhelms the numerator terms as $t \to 0$.  Thus the integral goes to zero as $t \to 0$.